# Magento 1: Email Marketing

Tags: magento-1, email, plugin, stores

I have a **virtual store** in magento and I want to know which is the best **plug-in email marketing or platform** that can be synchronized with magento 1, to do:

- an automatic email to send when the customer does not complete the
  purchase and sends for him a discounted email.
- automatic email for the birthdays of the month, on the anniversary
  day.
- an email for when the user has contracted the plan, send an email when this plan is close to expiring.
- automatic welcome email.
- automatic email when payment is not approved.
  Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the module by Aheadworks which meets most of your needs https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/follow-up-email.html

Comment: Do you only know this one?

Comment: Please find other modules too https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/sales-motivation/follow-up-trigger-email-suite.html.   https://marketplace.magento.com/magenest-magenest-hn-followupemail.html